# Title format is going beyond the pages

Tags: margins, titles

I am writing a short note with a title at the top in LaTeX. While it appears in the page, it goes beyond the top of the pages. Can you please inform me how to control (some command) so that the title will not go beyond the page.

*The code*:

```
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 

\begin{document} 

\title{\hfilneg \hfilneg \small{A note on the surjectivity of a class of weighted operator with the Muckenhoupt class Ap for p between one and infinity}} 

 \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you please post a minimal example reproducing the problem?

Comment: please wait  for a minute.

Comment: \documentclass[reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amssymb}



\begin{document}
\title{\hfilneg \hfilneg 
\small{A note on the surjectivity of a class of weighted operator with the Muckenhoupt class Ap for p between one and infinity}}

Comment: at the end there will be \end{document}

Comment: The above title is coming in the pages but it exceed above the page

Comment: It is used in the header (above the body text) but it is too long. You probably have to give a shorter version for the header (I don't know well the `amsart` class).

Comment: The example *as is* produce nothing. With a `\maketitle` after `\title{...}` produce a  title with three lines that no exceed the page margins in any way, so ...

Comment: @Fran: I think the O.P. means the header in the following pages overflows the page margins.

Comment: @Bernard I see. How about `\title[short title]{long title}`?

Comment: I don't know if this is a valid construct, I don't use  `amsmart`. Perhaps he'll have to code the headers directly.

Comment: @Bernarnad  Although do not use amsart either, as far I see works also without errors or warnings, so I would say it's valid.

Answer (score 2):

Use a short title version in the optional argument of `\title`. MWE:

```
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\begin{document} 
\title[Muckenhoupt weights $Ap$ between 0 and $\infty$]{A note 
on the sujectivity of a class of weighted operator with the 
Muckenhoupt class Ap for p between one and infinity} 
\maketitle
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```